Azure front door stops working with caching enabled
We've run into a very strange issue trying to setup azure frontdoor CDN. We've built a react front end client and all assets are configured to use the CDN URL so when the client loads in the browser, it requests the assets from the CDN instead. Everything works and the CDN returns those assets - right up until we enable caching which somewhat defeats the purpose of the CDN.
When we enable it, it suddenly takes a really long time to respond and eventually hits the 60 second timeout and closes the connection. As a result, we just end up with a blank page and can't use the app.
Has anyone come across this issue before and is there any specific config that we need to be aware of? As far as we can tell there's nothing fancy in our setup. One single origin pointing at the asset server and that's it.

The issue is when compression is turned on the server side (we had a Next.js app) it will return with HTTP 209 (Partially delivered) which confuses Front Door (don't really know what it does). Disabling compression and Front Door cache will work immediately.

Is the 209 response just a next.js thing (assume you meant 206 partial content?)? This app wasn't using next.js and I don't recall seeing a different response code to a direct request but this would explain what was happening

Well, not 100% sure how or why it was happening, but I made a few changes to the asset server itself and it's now working. Unsure if they were directly related or it's just a quirk in Azure, but make sure that the server has CORS headers set to allow everything, and that compression is disabled.

You need to disable compression in the Next app:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/compress
Then enable it in Frontdoor instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-compression#enabling-compression
As an added bonus this will offload the Next app, saving some CPU, and likely making it respond slightly faster.

This wasn't a next.js app and we didn't have compression enabled
